# WRT160NL Linksys Cisco Wifi router

Tags: security, router, wifi, physical-security

There is a WRT160NL Cisco Wifi router, and has to decrease the wifi range, so it cannot go outside of the office.

I tried to find this settings on the admin page, but I have not found yet.

Does anybody know what this setting could be?

I have removed the attenas, but it still gives strong signal,
still i have to advertise the SSID,
and of course its secured.

Thank you

Comment: That would be security by obscurity and not advisable.. Protect your wifi good enough or don't have wifi at all.

Answer (score 0):

Some more advanced router options are only accessible through telnet. You should be able to telnet your router's IP (e.g. telnet 192.168.1.1) and access those from the command line.

Comment: Also, removing the antennas could result in frying the router's circuits. If all else fails, you could create a small faraday cage around the router...

Comment: Any idea what command line commands do i have for this router? i have googled, and checked manual, but i found nothing. I just found how to telnet to the router, which worked, but what about after that?